# Finding questions or answers that deserve bounties

Tags: discussion, bounty

I believe we have some answers that deserve more recognition, and possibly some questions that deserve a little more attention than they may have received.

Bounties are one of the primary tools for fixing this problem, but I recognize that not everyone has enough reputation to feel comfortable posting bounties.

Therefore, I am making the following proposition:

If you have a question you want to see more attention, or know of an answer that you feel is outstanding and worthy of an additional award, post it here as an answer.

Post a link to the question or answer, along with a short description of who the person is you're nominating (so there's no ambiguity) and why you think the answer is awesome, or why you think the question deserves more attention.

Post only one suggestion per answer to this meta question, but you can post as many suggestions as separate answers as you'd like.

Please do not nominate your own question or answer; any self-promotion will be disqualified.

- Every answer that receives 2 upvotes will receive a bounty of at
  least 50 reputation.
- Every answer that receives 5 upvotes will receive a bounty of at least 100 reputation.
- Every answer that receives 10 upvotes will receive a bounty of 500 reputation.

Do note that bounty system restrictions mean that we can't give a second bounty on a question unless it is larger than the previous bounty. This means that if you nominate a question that has already had a bounty, or an answer to a question that has had a bounty already, it may not be eligible unless you earn enough votes on your recommendation to qualify for a bounty larger than the original.

As an additional incentive, the person who makes the suggestion in this meta thread that receives the most upvotes will have one of their answers awarded a 500 reputation bounty (you must have a positively scored answer to qualify).

Voting will be tallied on August 6th, exactly 2 weeks from the date and time of this post.  Any votes received after that time will not count for purposes of this contest.

So get out there and start finding those exceptional questions and answers!

**EDIT: Voting has closed.  Thanks to [Justkt](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/users/2146/justkt) for taking the time to find some suggestions.  I've set the bounties on the two questions that reached the nomination threshold of 2 votes (before the deadline; I see some votes were made after the eligibility period), and I will be awarding [Justkt's answer](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/8337/420) to [this question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/8332/420) a 500 point bounty.  I was pleased to find this answer, as I believe it merits an additional reward on its own, regardless of the offer I made in this meta discussion.  It is very detailed, thorough, and contains links to useful resources and citations.  That answer deserves more than the 10 upvotes it received, so I feel very good about awarding this bounty.**

Comment: Okay - this is fun! I will enjoy watching for great answers and questions. And very generous of you too!

Comment: Putting my 800 something rep on the table here too, just in case we need to reload :)

Comment: A note, this _is_ stretching the bounty system to a degree, but I'm comfortable with it. The end result is great content gets more recognition, something we could definitely use here.

Comment: @TimPost There is some established precedent for this.  I based my idea off of [arqade's holiday giveaway](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5560/8096) (and I borrowed some of the criteria from them).

Answer (score 2):

[At what age can children understand and respond well to discipline?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/3961/at-what-age-can-children-understand-and-respond-well-to-discipline)

The nomination is for the question.

I'm sure there are studies and psychological treatises out there on this topic, but none of the answers that exist cover them. Seems like a pressing topic for many parents of infants and toddlers.

Answer (score 1):

[How to stop a baby of trying to reach things he really wants?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/7293/how-to-stop-a-baby-of-trying-to-reach-things-that-he-really-wants)

The nomination is for the question.

The question title could use a little editing, but I think this is a great question that hasn't really gotten a solid answer yet. Really I think it is less about how to keep kids away from things you don't want them to touch and more about how you deal with infants in this screen-centric era. The AAP and other organizations say to limit screen time, but what does that practically mean? How do families determine what's appropriate for both parents and children when it comes to computer/tablet/smart phone/device usage around and by an infant?

Answer (score 1):

[How do I help my 4 month old nap longer?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/6944/how-do-i-help-my-4-month-old-nap-longer)

*I'm nominating this question, not my own answer to it.*

I did post an answer to this question, but it was merely a summation of my own research and experience. The 30-45 minute nap or single sleep cycle nap is a miserable experience for many parents of younger infants in the 2-ish to 8-ish month range as well as a few parents of older infants and toddlers. There's a **lot** on Google about it, and I believe if we can really get a superlative answer and get it to be a top Google hit it might draw a lot of traffic.